# Sendmail logging to mysql

Tags: mysql, email, sendmail

I am quite new to Linux and I've setup a Ubuntu 14 box with sendmail. I'd really like to pipe the output of the logs to Mysql for analysis with PHP.

My issue however is I can't even seem to start because there is no sendmail logs. I've sent email and received them but have looked in all the standard places but still can't see them.

Its not a problem if I can turn on the MySQL link/pipe without them but am struggling to see a) why I havent got any logs and b) how to get them to mysql.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail

Comment: Have already looked at that post and couldn't find them!

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sendmail-cookbook/0596004710/ch01s11.html

Comment: I looked at that too :o( It specifically talks about the configuration logs. Does sendmail not do this automatically when it installs? If not possible - how would you pipe it over to mysql?

Comment: I believe the log location is configurable. I can't comment on the rest ATM

Comment: How/where is it configured?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45471/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-antony).